# Running perfectly on IDE but line (if mat[j] == mat[colindex]:) is giving index out of range error when submitting on geeks for geeks

Tags: python, matrix, data-structures

```
t = int(input())
lis =[]
for i in range(t):
    col = list(map(int,input()))
    colindex = col[0] - 1
    count = 0
    matsize = col[0] * col[0]
    mat = list(map(int,input().split()))
    while len(lis) != matsize:
        for j in range(len(mat)):
            if colindex < len(mat):
                if mat[j] == mat[colindex]:
                    lis.append(mat[j])
                    colindex += col[0]
        count += 1
        colindex = col[0] - 1
        colindex -= count
    for i in lis:
        print(i,end= ' ')
```

Given a square matrix mat[][] of size N x N. The task is to rotate it by 90 degrees in anti-clockwise direction without using any extra space.

Input:
The first line of input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case consist of two lines. The first line of each test case consists of an integer N, where N is the size of the square matrix.The second line of each test case contains N x N space separated values of the matrix mat.

Output:
Corresponding to each test case, in a new line, print the rotated array.

Constraints:
1 ≤ T ≤ 50
1 ≤ N ≤ 50
1 <= mat[][] <= 100

Example:
Input:

2

3

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

2

5 7 10 9

Output:

3 6 9 2 5 8 1 4 7

7 9 5 10

Explanation:
Testcase 1: Matrix is as below:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Rotating it by 90 degrees in anticlockwise directions will result as below matrix:

3 6 9

2 5 8

1 4 7

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rotate-by-90-degree/0

Comment: Show us the full error output!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a problem with `j`. Can `colindex` ever be below 0? One way to identify this would be to simply keep track of the counters. For example, you can add an extra if condition `if colindex >= 0:` before `if mat[j] == mat[colindex]`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using one dimensional list, we can use two dimensional list to solve this challenge. From the given statement and sample test case, we get the following information:

- Print the rotated matrix in a single line.
- If the given matrix has `n` columns, the rotated matrix will have the sequential elements of `n-1`th column, `n-2`th column, .. `0`th column.

Here is my accepted solution of this challenge:

```
def get_rotated_matrix(ar, n):
    ar_2d = []
    for i in range(0, len(ar)-n+1, n):
        ar_2d.append(ar[i:i+n])
    result = []
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(n):
            result.append(str(ar_2d[j][i]))
    return result


cas = int(input())
for t in range(cas):
    n = int(input())
    ar = list(map(int, input().split()))
    result = get_rotated_matrix(ar, n)
    print(" ".join(result))
```

**Explanation:**

- To make the solution simple, I created a 2 dimensional list to store the input data as a 2D matrix called `ar_2d`.
- Then I traverse the matrix column wise; from last column to first column and appended the values to our `result` list as string value.
- Finally, I have printed the result with space between elements using `join` method.

**Disclaimer:**

My solution uses a 1D list to store the rotated matrix elements thus usages extra space.